# Best way to register two images to each-another in SITK?

Tags: registration, itk, simpleitk

I am very familiar with how to register one image to another in SITK, it's very simple. My question, however, is can I register images to each other? For example is there a way to transform moving image to 50% of the way to the fixed image, and then transform the fixed image to the 50% moved moving image? So that they're both co-registered to each other? Is this possible? In essence the reason why I want to do that is I want both to be transformed incase the transform induces any bias in the images. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For interpolating transforms, you could read this [thread](https://discourse.itk.org/t/scaling-multiplying-by-a-scalar-value-an-affine-transformation/4310). If the transform induces "bias", transforming both images halfway will not help.